# Copying columns from a worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Something is wrong with my code I can't figure out.

I'd like to copy a `column C` from `workbook 1` of `worksheet wsCopyFrom_OFP` to `column D` in `workbook 2` of `worksheet wsCopyTo` so that only rows with values will be copied

```
LastRow_OFP = wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(wsCopyFrom_OFP.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To LastRow_OFP
    wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(i, 3).Copy
    erow = wsCopyTo.Cells(wsCopyTo.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    wsCopyFrom_OFP.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(wsCopyTo).Cells(erow, 1)
Next i
```

Help very much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, salti. I guess you are mixing up the copy/paste code a bit. First you are copying the cell with `wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(i, 3).Copy` and then you are pasting it with `wsCopyFrom_OFP.Paste` to the same sheet (as your copied from). If you want to `copy` and `paste` in one line of VBA code then you can delete the row `wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(i, 3).Copy` altogether and alter the other row to `wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(i, 3).Copy Destination:=wsCopyTo.Cells(erow, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
LastRow_OFP = wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(wsCopyFrom_OFP.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 4 To LastRow_OFP
    wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(i, 3).Copy wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
Next i
```

**EDIT #1**

Try with below code

```
    LastRow_OFP = wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(wsCopyFrom_OFP.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To LastRow_OFP
        wsCopyFrom_OFP.Range("C" & i & ":C" & i + 3).Copy
        wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Next i
```

Comment: thanks a lot, How to make 3 line (wsCopyFrom_OFP.Cells(i, 3)......) copy pastespecial?

Comment: if you want to copy 3 line then it would be `wsCopyFrom_OFP.Range("C" & i & ":C" & i + 3).Copy wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)`

Comment: hmm....unfortunately it doesnt work. In col C of wsCopy_OFP I have a formula and I'd like it to be pasted special into the col A of wsCopyTo